# CimSession with Win32_NTLogEvent

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, event-log

I'm currently learning powershell and I'm trying to get the system and application eventlogs from multiple servers(errors and warnings only) using credentials.  For other things in this script I've been able to use a CimSession with Get-CimInstance, but it seems that doesn't work with Win32_NTLogEvent.  I've also tried looking into Get-WinEvent, but am unsure how to filter it down to only errors and warnings.  This is basically replacing what used to be Get-Eventlog, except now requiring credentials.

Previous code:

```
Get-Eventlog -LogName System -ComputerName $server -EntryType error,warning -Newest 20
Get-Eventlog -Logname Application -ComputerName $server -EntryType error,warning -Newest 20
```

Current Attempts:

As said I don't know how to filter the Entry Types like in Get-Eventlog with Get-WinEvent.

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName System -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred
```

And with Get-CimInstance I can't use a CimSession

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_NTLogEvent`
-filter 'type="error" or type="warning" and (logfile="system" or logfile="application")'`
|Select-Object -first 20
```

Would this be because Win32_NTLogEvent was from WMIObject or is there some other reason?  Is there something else I could use?  Or is there something I should be piping Get-WinEvent into?

Comment: Well I found a solution to it by using a powershell session to run get-eventlog.  Though if anyone has any answers, I'd still be interested in what could be done.

Comment: By the way I'm brand new here, and I'd appreciate it if you're going to downvote, that you'd at least have the decency to give an explanation as to why.  You're giving someone brand new to this site a rather negative view of it.

Comment: Your first example works for me `Get-Eventlog -Logname Application -computer "localhost" -EntryType error -Newest 20`

Comment: Well as I was using it for remote servers, it wouldn't work just alone.  Using it through a PSSession did though.
`$PSS= New-PSSession -computername $server -credential $cred (new line)
Invoke-command -session $PSS -scriptblock {
Get-Eventlog -Logname Application -EntryType error,warning -Newest 20}`

Also thank you to whoever it was that up voted the question from negative, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Get-winevent is the newer command.  Error and warning are level 2 & 3.  I'm surprised 'error' and 'warning' don't get converted to the right numbers.  The get-winevent docs aren't great on what the levels are. See [EventLevel Enum (System.Diagnostics.Tracing) _ Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventlevel?view=net-6.0).
There's also a workaround to use an array for logname or level over invoke-command.

```
invoke-command comp001 { $lognames = 'application','system'; $levels = 2,3; 
  get-winevent -filterhashtable @{logname=$lognames;level=$levels} -MaxEvents 5 }
```

You can certainly use -computername with get-ciminstance over wsman protocol (remote powershell).  Unlike powershell, "and" has a higher precedence than "or" in a filter.  Requesting both logfiles at once doesn't work well.

```
Get-CimInstance -computername comp001 Win32_NTLogEvent -filter '(type="error" 
  or type="warning") and logfile="application"' | Select-Object -first 20
```

Here's the event level enums:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel]2
Error

[System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel]3
Warning
```